# Suppose $X$ and $Y$ have joint pdf $f(x,y) = 0.5,$ for $0 \le x \le 1;$ $0\le y\le2.$ Evaluate $P (Y >X).$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, simulation

Kind of lost where to start with this. Could be easy but I don't know where to start simply by knowing $f(x, y) = 0.5.$

How can I find the probability $P(Y > X).$

Comment: It is impossible for any density to be negative: the question must stipulate $f(x,y)=0.5.$  To start, **draw a picture** of the region and the event $Y\gt X.$  You can find a large number of answered questions here that are just like this one.

Comment: Sorry, the neg sign was a typo (copy/paste from a html)

Comment: If you draw a picture as whuber suggests, you might even be able to come up with the correct answer $\frac 34$ by mere inspection of the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphical comment: Maybe this will get you started. First, $f(x,y)$ is the joint density function of $X$ and $Y.$

Your distribution is uniform on the rectangle shown below.
$10\,000$ realizations of $(X,Y)$ are plotted.
The diagonal blue line has equation $y = x.$

```
set.seed(2021)
x = runif(10^4, 0, 1)
y = runif(10^4, 0, 2)
plot(x, y, pch=".")
abline(a = 0, b=1, col="blue")
```

[image]

What proportion of the points lie above the blue line?

```
mean(y > x)
[1] 0.747   # aprx 3/4
```

You have stated the problem, but not shown any of your work
toward a solution. So I have no idea the level of your course
or what you have studied recently. All I have done is to use R to follow the suggestions of @whuber and @DilipSarwate.

You are on you own how
to present the solution suitably for your class.

Comment: Thanks. Pretty much matches my math:
$ \int_{x=0}^{1} \int_{y=x}^{2} f(x,y) \,dy \,dx = 
\int_{x=0}^{1} \int_{y=x}^{2} \frac{1}{2} \,dy \,dx =
\frac{1}{2} \int_{x=0}^{1} (2 - x) \, dx  = \frac{3}{4}$

Comment: Congratulations! From "kind of lost" to double integral in one page.

Comment: I tried to mark your answer as being the solution but I  don't have enough points :)

Comment: (a) If you continue on the site, you will be able to up-vote soon. (b) I guess you can click the check-mark to Accept answers now. (c) Glad you got a formal version of the answer, which was the point of this Q&A.

Comment: If a horizontal line is drawn from $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$ and another line through $(0,1)$ parallel to the line $y=x$ already shown, the answer $\frac 34$ can be written down by inspection instead of needing R to come up with 0.747 and then saying that it is approximately $\frac 34$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate True. On the other side though the dotting made it so intuitive, especially for problems like this in simulations.